# Android device incomplete JSON?

Tags: android, json

From my Android application I write a JSON string to a JSON-file located on an Android tablet in `/sdcard/subdirectory`, in the `onStop()`-method. This function executes succesfully.

If I copy this resulting `.json-file` from the Android device to my computer and I open this JSON-file in Notepad++, the JSON is not valid: it is incomplete.

This is the content of said JSON-file:

```
{... there are about 20 of these elements, I won't list them all for readability...},
{"name":"Marker7","long":2.924128,"lat":51.204594,"warning":"Sharp turn"},
{"name":"Marker8","long":2.9260479999999998,"lat":51.203364,"warning":"Dead end"},
{"name":"Marker9","long":2.926252,"lat":51.203209,"warning":"
```

As you can see, the JSON is cut off at the `warning` part of `Marker9`, making this invalid JSON.

What is weird is the following: my application also reads from this file in the `onCreate()`-method, and if I print this JSON, it does show the correct and complete JSON! So within my Android app I don't experience any issues, and I assume my writing method and the resulting JSON-file is working as intended since the correct data is retrieved from the reading-function. However if I want to copy this JSON and use it elsewhere I won't have a valid JSON-file.

Why is this? Does this have something to do with the **ext4**-filesystem that my Android device is using?

I also noticed that this seems to happen when the file reaches the **1.18kB** size mark (as shown in my explorer view, but again: the correct and complete IS retrieved within the Android app...), because each time I copy the file and it appears to be cut off, the size is always exactly 1.18kB.

### Update

The code for reading the JSON:

```
public String loadJSON() {
        String json = null;
        try {

            //InputStream is = getAssets().open("markers.json");
            File jsonFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "osmdroid/markers.json");
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(jsonFile);

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }

private void readJsonMarkers() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSON());
        JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("markers");
        System.out.println("JSON LOAD: " + jsonArray);  // this shows the correct, full list of markers
    }
```

The code for writing the JSON:

```
private void writeJsonMarkers() throws JSONException {
    JSONArray data = new JSONArray();

    for(OverlayItem oi: waypointMarkers){
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("name", oi.getTitle());
            obj.put("long", oi.getPoint().getLongitude());
            obj.put("lat", oi.getPoint().getLatitude());
            obj.put("warning", oi.getSnippet());
            data.put(obj);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(loadJSON());
    rootObj.remove("markers");
    rootObj.put("markers",data);
    // this method is used to remove the existing markers-list from the JSON, and add an updated markers-list to it

    File jsonFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "osmdroid/markers.json");

    try {
        FileWriter jsonWriter = new FileWriter(jsonFile);
        jsonWriter.write(rootObj.toString());
        jsonWriter.flush();
        jsonWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: is there any special character into your JSON after "warning" ?

Comment: No, just a normal string: "School"

Comment: Are you sure your onCreate reads from this file? And not from your server? If you post your code, it will help us to help you.

Comment: I updated my question with the requested code.